# Animation in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, animation

I am having difficulties in completing a task which requires to display lines as animations in a web app.

The lines data is stored in a database and consists of x, y and time information. The x and y coordinates specify the position of the drawn points whereas time represents the timestamps (in milliseconds) of the respective points.

For instance, 
    point 1 (x=10, y=23, t=152) 
    point 2 (x=21, y=29, t=385)
    point 3 (x=15, y=20, t=506)
    ...
    ...

So, the task is to display these points in a web app based on the given timestamps.

My problem is first that I do not know what kind of graphical plugin to use and then how to implement it (that is how to use timers, how to do the animation, etc).

I would appreciate any help from you! Please let me know in case you need more information about this task. I would gladly provide it.

Kind regards,
Frida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would use [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) for something like this. It is easy to use and has support for all major browsers. The animated line drawing can be a little troublesome because you have to generate each step as a seperate path, but it shouldn't be to hard.

Here is a very simple example

```
var points = [
    { x: 0, y: 0, t: 0 },
    { x: 100, y: 230, t: 1520 },
    { x: 210, y: 290, t: 3850 },
    { x: 150, y: 200, t: 5060 },
];

var paths = [];

// build paths
points.forEach(function (p, idx) {
    if (idx === 0) {
        paths.push('M ' + p.x + ' ' + p.y);
    } else {
        paths.push(paths[idx - 1] + ' L ' + p.x + ' ' + p.y);
    }
});

var paper = Raphael(10, 10, 300, 300);
var line = paper.path(paths[0]);

var next = 1;

function animate() {
    if (paths[next]) {  
        duration = points[next].t - points[next - 1].t        
        line.animate({ path: paths[next] }, duration, 'linear', animate);
        next++;
    }
}
animate();
```

And here is a fiddle where you can see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/toxicsyntax/FLPdr/    ​
**UPDATE**

Here is a complete HTML page that uses the above code. It is still a simplified example, but you should be able to work your way from that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Raphael Play</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/master/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function drawLine(points) {

                var paths = ['M ' + points[0].x + ' ' + points[0].y];

                // build paths
                for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
                    var p = points[i];
                    paths.push(paths[i - 1] + ' L ' + p.x + ' ' + p.y);
                }

                // get drawing surface
                var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 500);  

                // draw line
                var line = paper.path(paths[0]);
                var next = 1;

                function animate() {
                    if (paths[next]) {  
                        duration = points[next].t - points[next - 1].t        
                        line.animate({ path: paths[next] }, duration, 'linear', animate);
                        next++;
                    }
                }
                animate();
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #canvas_container {
                width: 500px;
                border: 1px solid #aaa;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvas_container"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                // the points here should be generated by your ASP.NET application
                drawLine([
                    // the points here should be generated by your ASP.NET application
                    { x: 0, y: 0, t: 0 },
                    { x: 100, y: 230, t: 1520 },
                    { x: 210, y: 290, t: 3850 },
                    { x: 150, y: 200, t: 5060 },
                ]);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The points are at the end of the HTML page, and in your application you could generate those from your model.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! This will certainly be useful to me. However, since I am new to web development I tried to run a simple example with Raphael but, unfortunately, could not succeed. Therefore would kindly ask from you, if it is possible, to report a complete example how could I run your code? Kind regards, Frida!

Comment: I have add an html example that uses my code. I think an introduction to Raphael is a bit out of scope for this answer, but you can have a look at this one if you like: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/an-introduction-to-the-raphael-js-library/

Comment: Dear AHM! I would appreciate if you could help me with one more thing. So far, I have managed to retrieve the x, y and t arrays from db and insert them into Javascript arrays as shown below Dim arrayX_name As String = "js_X"
        Dim arrayX_values As String = "100, 210, 150"
        csm.RegisterArrayDeclaration(arrayX_name, arrayX_values) The same was done for y and t data as well. I am facing a problem in finding a way to enter this data into drawLine() function you created with Raphael. Could you please help me with this? Kind regards, Frida!

Comment: One more thing, how shall I alter the function if I want to display only points and not lines? /Frida

Comment: As for a way to enter the points into the function, you can simply output the javascript block the same way you would output HTML. This is not strictly the cleanest way to send the data, but I think it should work fine for your purpose. If you want to draw points instead of lines the function needs a rewrite. Again, I would encourage you to read some raphaël tutorials and try if you can do this yourself.

Comment: How can I pass the ASP.NET variables to Javascript variables in an efficient manner?

Comment: Problem solved! For those who are looking for a similar solution here comes the description. 1) in page load, populate a gridview; 2) populate three dropdowns (for x,y,t); 3) loop through dropdownlist to save data into JS arrays using: var ddlArray_X = new Array(); var ddl_X = document.getElementById('DropDownListX'); for (i = 0; i < ddl_X.options.length; i++) {ddlArray_X[i] = ddl_X.options[i].value;}; 4) Create an associative array from the three arrays and 5) Enter this array into drawline(), as designed by @AHM. P.S. I would like to get help in rewriting drawline() to display points. Thanks